# Marca d'agua com imagens em produção

Tags: php

Preciso colocar marca d'agua em imagens que já estão em produção, eu dei uma pesquisada e só encontrei formas de fazer isso durante o upload da imagem, mas teria como aplicar a marca d'agua durante a renderização da imagem?

Comment: Sim, tem. Ao invés de você adicionar o link direto para a imagem, você pode inserir um link para um script PHP, informando a imagem desejada. O script busca nos arquivos a imagem, insere a marca d'água e retorna a imagem - podendo salvar novamente em arquivo para evitar o mesmo processo futuramente.

Comment: Entendi, no meu caso essas imagens estão com o nome salvo no banco, então eu teria chamar o script que aplica a marca d'agua e o invés de salvar uma nova imagem seria necessário substituir a mesma...só que assim o spcript iria aplicar a marca d'agua todas as vezes que a imagem fosse requisitada...ou entao posso fazer pelo modo mais dificil que é salvar uma nova imagem e atualizar o nome no banco, não tem outro jeito né?